# Scala: a template for function to accept only a certain arity and a certain output?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a class, where all of its functions have the same arity and same type of output. (Why? Each function is a separate processor that is applied to a Spark DataFrame and yields another DataFrame).

So, the class looks like this:

```
class Processors {
   def p1(df: DataFrame): DataFrame {...}
   def p2(df: DataFrame): DataFrame {...}
   def p3(df: DataFrame): DataFrame {...}
...
}
```

I then apply all the methods of a given DataFrame by mapping over `Processors.getClass.getMethod`, which allows me to add more processors without changing anything else in the code.

What I'd like to do is define a template to the methods under `Processors` which will restrict all of them to accept only one DataFrame and return a DataFrame. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @Paul I'm not sure I follow you.. can you provide a sample code, please?

Comment: @shakedzy Are all these processors actually declared in the same class?

Comment: If you're already planning to use run-time reflection (not usually my first choice), why not examine the signatures of the methods to filter out ones that don't match what you want?

Comment: Yuval - yes ; Joe - that's an option.. how is this done? Can you please add a sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing a restriction on what kind of functions can be added to a "list" is possible by using an appropriate container class instead of a generic class to hold the methods that are restricted.  The container of restricted methods can then be part of some new class or object or part of the main program.

What you lose below by using containers (e.g. a Map with string keys and restricted values) to hold specific kinds of functions is compile-time checking of the names of the methods.  e.g. calling triple vs trilpe

The restriction of a function to take a type T and return that same type T can be defined as a `type F[T]` using [Function1 from the scala standard library](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/Function1.html). `Function1[A,B]` allows any single-parameter function with input type A and output type B, but we want these input/output types to be the same, so:

`type F[T] = Function1[T,T]`

For a container, I will demonstrate [`scala.collection.mutable.ListMap[String,F[T]]`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/collection/mutable/ListMap.html) assuming the following requirements:

- string names reference the functions (doThis, doThat, instead of 1, 2, 3...)
- functions can be added to the list later (mutable)

though you could choose some other mutable or immutable collection class (e.g. `Vector[F[T]]` if you only want to number the methods) and still benefit from the restriction of what kind of functions future developers can include into the container.

An abstract type can be defined as:

`type TaskMap[T] = ListMap[String, F[T]]`

For your specific application you would then instantiate this as:

```
val Processors:TaskMap[Dataframe] = ListMap(
   "p1" -> ((df: DataFrame) => {...code for p1 goes here...}),
   "p2" -> ((df: DataFrame) => {...code for p2 goes here...}),
   "p3" -> ((df: DataFrame) => {...code for p3 goes here...})
)
```

and then to call one of these functions you use

```
Processors("p2")(someDF)
```

For simplicity of demonstration, let's forget about Dataframes for a moment and consider whether this scheme works with integers.

Consider the short program below. The collection "myTasks" can only contain functions from Int to Int. All of the lines below have been **tested** in the scala interpreter, v2.11.6, so you can follow along line by line.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListMap
type F[T] = Function1[T,T]
type TaskMap[T] = ListMap[String, F[T]]
val myTasks: TaskMap[Int] = ListMap(
    "negate" -> ((x:Int)=>(-x)),
    "triple" -> ((x:Int)=>(3*x))
)
```

we can add a new function to the container that adds 7 and name it "add7"

```
myTasks += ( "add7" -> ((x:Int)=>(x+7)) )
```

and the scala interpreter responds with:

```
res0: myTasks.type = Map(add7 -> <function1>, negate -> <function1>, triple -> <function1>)
```

but we can't add a function named "half" because it would return a Float, and a Float is not an Int and should trigger a type error

```
myTasks += ( "half" -> ((x:Int)=>(0.5*x)) )
```

Here we get this error message:

```
scala> myTasks += ( "half" -> ((x:Int)=>(0.5*x)) )
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Double
 required: Int
              myTasks += ( "half" -> ((x:Int)=>(0.5*x)) )
                                                   ^
```

In a compiled application, this would be found at compile time.

How to call the functions stored this way is a bit more verbose for single calls, but can be very convenient.

Suppose we want to call "triple" on 10.

We can't write

```
   triple(10)
   <console>:9: error: not found: value triple
```

Instead it is

```
 myTasks("triple")(10)
 res4: Int = 30
```

Where this notation becomes more useful is if you have a list of tasks to perform but only want to allow tasks listed in myTasks.

Suppose we want to run all the tasks on the input data "10"

```
 myTasks mapValues { _ apply 10 }
 res9: scala.collection.Map[String,Int] = 
    Map(add7 -> 17, negate -> -10, triple -> 30)
```

Suppose we want to triple, then add7, then negate

If each result is desired separately, as above, that becomes:

```
 List("triple","add7","negate") map myTasks.apply map { _ apply 10 } 
 res11: List[Int] = List(30, 17, -10)
```

But "triple, then add 7, then negate" could also be describing a series of steps to do 10, i.e. we want -((3*10)+7)" and scala can do that too

```
 val myProgram = List("triple","add7","negate") 
 myProgram map myTasks.apply reduceLeft { _ andThen _ }  apply 10 
 res12: Int = -37
```

opening the door to writing an interpreter for your own customizable set of tasks because we can also write

```
 val magic = myProgram map myTasks.apply reduceLeft { _ andThen _ }
```

and `magic` is then a **function** from int to int that can take aribtrary ints or otherwise do work as a function should.

```
scala> magic(1)
res14: Int = -10

scala> magic(2)
res15: Int = -13

scala> magic(3)
res16: Int = -16

scala> List(10,20,30) map magic
res17: List[Int] = List(-37, -67, -97)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

```
class Processors {
  type Template = DataFrame => DataFrame

  val p1: Template = ...
  val p2: Template = ...
  val p3: Template = ...

  def applyAll(df: DataFrame): DataFrame =
    p1(p2(p3(df)))
}
```

Comment: I think he wants to restrict the shape of the methods to only accept a dataframe and return one.

Comment: Do do you want to do than is not achieved by this type alias?

Comment: Olivier - not really, as I can still define methods that are not of this template. I'd like a restriction.

Comment: That's impossible.